# Microsoft Graph Api Python

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to execute microsoft graph requests as : `"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"` , `"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages"` and so on, on my python script

While testing those requests using this web interface https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/graph-explorer, all requests worked

On my script, only this request work `"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"`, other requests i get errors

Here is my script :

```
import msal
import jwt
import json
import sys
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from msal_extensions import *
graphURI = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
tenantID = 'my tenant id'
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantID
clientID = 'my client id'
scope = ["email Files.ReadWrite.All", "Mail.Read", "Mail.Read.Shared", "Mail.ReadBasic", "Mail.ReadWrite", "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared MailboxSettings.Read MailboxSettings.ReadWrite openid profile Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All"]
username = 'yourAADUsername' # i keep this one like this, i don't know what is my username
result = None
tokenExpiry = None
def msal_persistence(location, fallback_to_plaintext=False):
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        return FilePersistenceWithDataProtection(location)
    if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        return KeychainPersistence(location, "my_service_name", "my_account_name")
        return FilePersistence(location)
def msal_cache_accounts(clientID, authority):
# Accounts
    persistence = msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
    print("Is this MSAL persistence cache encrypted?", persistence.is_encrypted)
    cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
    app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id=clientID, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
    accounts = app.get_accounts()
    print(accounts)
    return accounts
def msal_delegated_refresh(clientID, scope, authority, account):
    persistence = msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
    cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
    app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id=clientID, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
    result = app.acquire_token_silent_with_error(
    scopes=scope, account=account)
    return result
def msal_delegated_refresh_force(clientID, scope, authority, account):
    persistence = msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
    cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
    app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id=clientID, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
    result = app.acquire_token_silent_with_error(
    scopes=scope, account=account, force_refresh=True)
    return result
def msal_delegated_device_flow(clientID, scope, authority):
    print("Initiate Device Code Flow to get an AAD Access Token.")
    print("Open a browser window and paste in the URL below and then enter the Code. CTRL+C to cancel.")
    persistence = msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
    cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
    app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id=clientID, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
    flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=scope)
    if "user_code" not in flow:
        raise ValueError("Fail to create device flow. Err: %s" % json.dumps(flow, indent=4))
    print(flow["message"])
    sys.stdout.flush()
    result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(flow)
    return result
def msal_jwt_expiry(accessToken):
    decodedAccessToken = jwt.decode(accessToken, verify=False)
    accessTokenFormatted = json.dumps(decodedAccessToken, indent=2)
    # Token Expiry
    tokenExpiry = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(decodedAccessToken['exp']))
    print("Token Expires at: " + str(tokenExpiry))
    return tokenExpiry
def msgraph_request(resource, requestHeaders):
    # Request
    results = requests.get(resource, headers=requestHeaders).json()
    return results
accounts = msal_cache_accounts(clientID, authority)
if accounts:
    for account in accounts:
        if account['username'] == username:
            myAccount = account
            print("Found account in MSAL Cache: " + account['username'])
            print("Obtaining a new Access Token using the Refresh Token")
            result = msal_delegated_refresh(clientID, scope, authority, myAccount)
print(result)
if result is None:
    # Get a new Access Token using the Device Code Flow
    result = msal_delegated_device_flow(clientID, scope, authority)
    print(result)
else:
    if result["access_token"]:
        msal_jwt_expiry(result["access_token"])
    else:
        # Get a new Access Token using the Device Code Flow
        result = msal_delegated_device_flow(clientID, scope, authority)
if result["access_token"]:
    msal_jwt_expiry(result["access_token"])
    # Query AAD Users based on voice query using DisplayName
    print(graphURI + "/v1.0/me")

requestHeaders = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result["access_token"],'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
queryResults = msgraph_request(graphURI + "/v1.0/me",requestHeaders)
print(json.dumps(queryResults, indent=2))
```

So when i execute this query :     `queryResults = msgraph_request(graphURI + "/v1.0/me",requestHeaders)`

the output is:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "businessPhones": [],
  "displayName": "Joe Coral",
  "givenName": "Joe",
  "jobTitle": null,
  "mail": null,
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": null,
  "preferredLanguage": "en",
  "surname": "Coral",
  "userPrincipalName": "joe-coral-hotmail.fr#EXT#@joecoralhotmail.onmicrosoft.com",
  "id": "82a2ef56-dbb7-45a4-bc9c-c533fd2c5908"
}
```

but when i use this query: `queryResults = msgraph_request(graphURI + "/v1.0/me/messages",requestHeaders)`

the output is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-06-08T15:03:31",
      "request-id": "fa8dc282-0c8d-4be4-a195-4488c4f86e23",
      "client-request-id": "fa8dc282-0c8d-4be4-a195-4488c4f86e23"
    }
  }
}
```

And on my application on ADD, i granted all permissions :

[image: PERMISSIONS]

Comment: Did you have exchange license for your account?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your result of the `/v1.0/me` request, I can see that the user is a personal Microsoft account and has been added into this AAD tenant as a guest.

When you sign into https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/graph-explorer with this user, it actually treats your account as a personal Microsoft account rather than a guest user.

This is because Microsoft Graph Explorer uses `common` endpoint for authentication. (See details from my [pervious answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65187383/accessing-onenote-via-graph-api?answertab=votes#tab-top))

But in your code, I see that you put `authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantID`, which means it will treats your account as a guest user in this tenant.

In this case, when you call `/v1.0/me/messages`, it will try to get messages from your O365 mailbox hosted in Exchange Online. But the guest user doesn't have Exchange Online license and it's not hosted in Exchange Online. That is why you get `ResourceNotFound` error.

Therefore, based on your description, I think you are trying to get messages for the  user as a personal Microsoft account rather than a guest user.

Please modify `authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantID` to `authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'`. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i changed authority and got this error : jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Not enough segments
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @ibrahim This is because that access token for personal Microsoft account is not a jwt token. You cannot use `jwt.decode` on it. As a workaround, you can try to get the id token and decode it.